# vim: How to replace line breaks within a specific XML node?

Tags: xml, vim, sed

How do I replace line breaks within a specific XML node?

E.g.: `^J` to `<br/>` within `<content:encoded></content:encoded>`

Sample of the code:

```
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[
      Communities across the Northwest Territories have harvested a bumper crop

      of produce ranging from potatoes and carrots to spinach and lettuce thanks to

      dedicated community gardeners and the Government of the Northwest Territories’ (GNWT).
    ]></content:encoded>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one such range, the following will do:

```
/<content:encoded>/,/<\/content:encoded>/s#$#<br/>#
```

This executes a `:substitute` command over the range delimited by the (opening / closing) tags. The example *adds* the `<br/>` tag, if you want to condense everything into one line, search for `\n` instead of `$` (`\n\s*` to also remove the indent).

If there are multiple such tags that you want to replace, prepend `:global` to the command. This will execute the substitute (this time from the current line containing the start tag to the next end tag) for *all* tags found in the buffer (which you can again influence by prepending a different range, e.g. `1,100global`).

Comment: I'm sure other solutions are just as good, but this one worked perfectly for me.
`global/<content:encoded>/,/<\/content:encoded>/s#$#<br/>#`

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to accept an answer (by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro:

1. `qq` start recording
2. `/content:encoded<cr>` go to next tag. Note `<cr>` means hit enter.
3. `vit` visually select in tag
4. `:'<,'>s/\n\s*/<br\/>/g` replace all newlines followed by any number of spaces with `<br/>`. Note the `'<,'>` will automatically be added by vim.
5. `q` stop recording
6. `5@q` repeat 5 times.

It's probably possible using regex too but my regex foo isnt up to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper XML handling tool. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
for my $text in //content:encoded/text() {
    my $lines = xsh:split("\n", $text) ;
    for $lines {
        my $t := insert text (.) before $text ;
        insert element br before $text ;
    }
    delete $text;
}
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to visually select the lines, then `:s#\n#<br/>\r#g` - it will replace the line endings to `<br/>`.

If you want to replace it in every inner tag, then you shuld use:

`:g /<content:encoded>/;/\/content:encoded/ s#\n#<br/>\r#g`